# Activation of character's effects (RE: DBG)

Tags: resident-evil-deck-building-game

If you have enough decorations to activate lvl 1 and lvl 2 character's effects, can you activate BOTH effects or you must choose ONLY ONE of them?

Answer (score 3):

From the ruleboook ([source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xai11ce8817kfru/RE1_Rulebook.pdf?dl=0)), page 10:

> **LEVEL UP!**
> When a Character has received a certain amount (or more) of the indicated Decorations, that Character “levels up”, giving you access to more powerful effects to aid you in your escape. When a Character becomes Level 2, that Character has all of the abilities of Level 1 as well as Level 2.

So yes, when a charachter becomes level 2 they can use all abilities of level 1 and level 2.